# Why build errors when connecting timers in Quartus ii?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I use the Nios 2 IDE from Altera with the Altera DE2. I add a file `Functions.c` with code that needs a timer e.g.

```
int main ()
{
  int w[8192];

  int a, b;
  int size = M;

  printf("Working Set\n\n");
  printf("Information about the system:\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("Processor Type: %s\n", NIOS2_CPU_IMPLEMENTATION);
  printf("Size Instruction Cache: %d\n", NIOS2_ICACHE_SIZE);
  printf("Line Size Instruction Cache: %d\n", NIOS2_ICACHE_LINE_SIZE);
  printf("Size Data Cache: %d\n", NIOS2_DCACHE_SIZE);
  printf("Line Size Data Cache: %d\n\n\n", NIOS2_DCACHE_LINE_SIZE);

  /* Check if timer available */
  if (alt_timestamp_start() < 0)
    printf("No timestamp device available!");
  else
    {

      /* Print Information about the system */
      printf("Information about the system:\n");
      printf("\n");

      /* Print frequency and period */
      printf("Timestamp frequency: %3.1f MHz\n", (float)alt_timestamp_freq()/1000000.0);
      printf("Timestamp period:    %f ms\n\n", 1000.0/(float)alt_timestamp_freq());  


      /* Calculate Timer Overhead */
      // Average of 10 measurements */
      int i;
      timer_overhead = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {      
        start_measurement();
        stop_measurement();
        timer_overhead = timer_overhead + time_2 - time_1;
      }
      timer_overhead = timer_overhead / 10;

      printf("Timer overhead in ticks: %d\n", (int) timer_overhead);
      printf("Timer overhead in ms:    %f\n", 
         1000.0 * (float)timer_overhead/(float)alt_timestamp_freq());


    // === Task 1 : Block Sizes ===

    // Function 1.1
    initArray(w, 8192);
    printf("Function 1.1: ");
    start_measurement();    
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++)
       w[i]++;
    stop_measurement();
    printf("%5.2f us", (float) microseconds(ticks - timer_overhead));
    printf("(%d ticks)\n", (int) (ticks - timer_overhead)); 


      printf("Done!\n");

  }    
  return 0;
}
```

But I get build errors when trying with different timers in the system properties time. Can you tell me how I should connect the timers?

[image]

I suppose that I should not build with no system timer and adding the file requires a timer. When I add the file I get these errors.

```
make -s all includes 
Compiling Functions.c...
../Functions.c: In function `microseconds':
../Functions.c:20: warning: implicit declaration of function `alt_timestamp_freq'
../Functions.c: In function `start_measurement':
../Functions.c:35: warning: implicit declaration of function `alt_dcache_flush_all'
../Functions.c:36: warning: implicit declaration of function `alt_icache_flush_all'
../Functions.c:38: warning: implicit declaration of function `alt_timestamp_start'
../Functions.c:39: warning: implicit declaration of function `alt_timestamp'
../Functions.c: In function `main':
../Functions.c:58: error: `NIOS2_CPU_IMPLEMENTATION' undeclared (first use in this function)
../Functions.c:58: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../Functions.c:58: error: for each function it appears in.)
../Functions.c:59: error: `NIOS2_ICACHE_SIZE' undeclared (first use in this function)
../Functions.c:60: error: `NIOS2_ICACHE_LINE_SIZE' undeclared (first use in this function)
../Functions.c:61: error: `NIOS2_DCACHE_SIZE' undeclared (first use in this function)
../Functions.c:62: error: `NIOS2_DCACHE_LINE_SIZE' undeclared (first use in this function)
../Functions.c:52: warning: unused variable `a'
../Functions.c:52: warning: unused variable `b'
../Functions.c:53: warning: unused variable `size'
make: *** [obj/Functions.o] Error 1
Build completed in 2.3 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NIOS2_CPU_IMPLEMENTATION` and other undeclared identifiers are defined in `system.h` file, generated with BSP. It looks like you forgot to include this library in your code.

Problems with implicit declarations are caused by not included `sys/alt_timestamp.h` library.